# How to implement MouseWheelListener for JPanel without breaking its default implementation?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, mousewheel

Simply; I have a `JPanel` inside a `JScrollPane`;

As expected; `JScrollPane` by default listens to `MouseWheelEvent` so that scrolling is working well for when the wheel is rotating and while the cursor is hovering over the `JPanel`.

**But** After that; I just updated `JPanel` so that it implements `MouseWheelListener`, and I added this mouse wheel listener for the `JPanel` itself.

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    if (e.isControlDown()) {
        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
            System.out.println("mouse wheel Up");
        } else {
            System.out.println("mouse wheel Down");
        }
    }
}
```

The `JPanel` responds to this implementation for when both; the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed down and the wheel is rotating and while the cursor is hovering over the `JPanel`. But the default behaviour of the `JScrollPane` is unexpectedly lost!!!

When I rotate the wheel while the cursor is hovering over the `JPanel` the scrolls of the `JScrollPane` is not responding!!!

It seems that; this implementation of `MouseWheelListener` breaks the default of a `JPanel`.

So; How to implement `MouseWheelListener` for `JPanel` without breaking its default implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`MouseWheelEvents` and the scrolling behavior have some subtle caveats.

For example, when you open this page (I mean THIS one, which you are currently reading), place the mouse in the middle, and start srolling down with the wheel, you will scroll over the code snippets. Note that *although* the code snippets are contained in code blocks that *have a scrollbar*, continuously rotating the mouse wheel will **not** trigger a scrolling **in** the code blocks, but only in the whole page. But when you once *move* the mouse while it is *inside* a code block, and *afterwards* roll the mouse wheel, then you will scroll in the code block only - and **not** the whole page.

Similarly, rotating the mouse wheel may not affect the hovered scrollable. I think it depends on the Window Manager and the Look & Feel, but in some cases, you will scroll *the scroll pane that contains the focussed component* - even if the mouse cursor is outside of this component, and even if it is over a scollable component (you can also observe this, for example, in the Windows Explorer)!

---

However, some of these mechanisms and subtleties can be found in the Swing components as well. For example, the [redispatching mechanism](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/3e95aadb479f/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#l4762) that passes `MouseWheelEvents` to the ancestors if they are not handled by the component itself.

Following this pattern, a solution (that is conceptually similar to [the one that LuxxMiner proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259298/3182664), but may be a tad more generic) may be to simply re-dispatch the `MouseWheelEvent` to the parent component:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseWheelListenerForPanelInScrollpane
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        MouseWheelListenerPanel m = new MouseWheelListenerPanel();
        m.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,4000));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(m);
        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MouseWheelListenerPanel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener
{
    MouseWheelListenerPanel()
    {
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
    {
        if (e.isControlDown())
        {
            if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("mouse wheel Up");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("mouse wheel Down");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            getParent().dispatchEvent(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add an `else` to re-dispatch the event directly to the scroll pane if ctrl is *not* down:

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    if (e.isControlDown()) {
        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
            System.out.println("mouse wheel Up");
        } else {
            System.out.println("mouse wheel Down");
        }
    } else {
        // pass the event on to the scroll pane
        getParent().dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this really qualifies as an proper answer, since it's kind of a workaround, but I came up with the following solution: Just invoke the `mouseWheelMoved` method of the `scrollPane` only when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> isn't being pressed:

```
if (e.isControlDown()) {
    if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
        infoLabel.setText("Mouse Wheel Up");
    } else {
        infoLabel.setText("Mouse Wheel Down");
    }
} else {
    scrollPane.getListeners(MouseWheelListener.class)[0].mouseWheelMoved(e);
}
```

**Full Example:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Example {
    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new ScrollPanePanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ScrollPanePanel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener {
    private JLabel infoLabel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public ScrollPanePanel() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label " + i));
        }
        panel.addMouseWheelListener(this);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        infoLabel = new JLabel(" ");
        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.add(infoLabel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (e.isControlDown()) {
            if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
                infoLabel.setText("Mouse Wheel Up");
            } else {
                infoLabel.setText("Mouse Wheel Down");
            }
        } else {
            scrollPane.getListeners(MouseWheelListener.class)[0].mouseWheelMoved(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry; both solutions work like this: When I press down [Ctrl] while rotating the wheel of the mouse -  it unnecessarily invoke both; My implemented `MouseWheelListener` and the default scrolling of the page - How to stop the default scrolling while pressing [Ctrl]

Comment: @SalehFeek Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See my updated code, I hope it works now. It should only update the text when pressing CTRL and should only invoke the default scrolling of the `JScrollPane` when *not* pressing CTRL.

Comment: Your solution now is working OK - Thanks - But I have a small question: this line is invoked repeatedly as the wheel  moves `scrollPane.getListeners(MouseWheelListener.class)[0].mouseWheelMoved(e);`- so my question is; is it a wise practice to invoke repeatedly the same line of code like this; whereas it achieves the same thing every time?!

Comment: @SalehFeek The `getListeners` part of it probably isn't wise, I think the solution with `dispatchEvent()` that Ian Roberts and Marco13 mentioned is better. I don't see a problem with invoking the same line of code every time though.